# Find a non-trivial solution to $5x^2+7y^2=3z^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find a non-trivial solution to $5x^2+7y^2=3z^2$. Note: $x,y,z$ are integers.

My attempt: By a theorem I have $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ and $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. I just guessed $x=1$. So I have $5+7y^2=3z^2$. I now guessed $y=1$ and $z=2$.

Is there a better way to find non-trivial solutions than guessing?

Comment: Are $x$, $y$ and $z$ integers?

Comment: @QuestionAsker, of course. Else why should we have do so much attempt?

Comment: Yes - but it would be nice if that was explicitly stated in the question. In addition, it would be nice if the name of the particular theorem could be stated too.

Comment: Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$. A non-trivial solution to $ax^2+by^2=cz^2$ exists if $x^2 \equiv bc \pmod a$, $x^2 \equiv ac \pmod b$ and $x^2 \equiv -ab \pmod c$ have solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existence of integer solutions of $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$ or other ternary quadratic forms can be decided by using Legendre's theorem.

**Theorem** (Legendre): Let $a,b,c$ coprime positive integers, then $ax^2 + by^2 = cz^2$ has a nontrivial solution in integers (or rational numbers) $x,y,z$ if and only if $$\left(\frac{-bc}{a}\right)=\left(\frac{-ac}{b}\right)=\left(\frac{ab}{c}\right)=1.$$

If such solutions exists one can use a theorem of Holzer, that $x,y,z$ must be relatively small (provided $a,b,c$ are squarefree), i.e., $|x|\le \sqrt{|bc|}$, $|y|\le \sqrt{|ca|}$, and $|z|\le \sqrt{|ab|}$, so that one can search by computer (there are more effective algorithms, though, than just trying here).

Reference for finding explicitly solutions: J. E. Cremona, D. Rusin: Efficient solution of rational conics. Math. Comp. 72 (2003), no. 243, 1417 1441.

Comment: How can I translate the last line into solutions?

Comment: @Dietrich: I assume $\displaystyle \Big(\frac{a}{p}\Big)$ is the [_Legendre symbol_](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreSymbol.html)?

Comment: Yes, some people also write $a\square p$ to denote that $a$ is a square modulo $p$. For example, Pete Clark writes the conditions in Legendre's theorem as $ab\square c$, $-bc\square a$, $-ca\square b$.